# How long do I need to wait to reconnect to the pokemon bank after it is "locked" due to interrupted communication?

Tags: pokemon-bank

I have been trying to transfer over all my old pokemon and I think I may have overdone it.  I am receiving the error:

> Communication with the server was interrupted during your previous
>   session, so the server has been locked.  Please wait a short while and
>   then try to connect again.

Is there a specific time that the server is discretizing so as to keep me from constantly trying to reconnect?  And as a follow up, is this (probably) actually due to a disconnect or is the bank trying to limit my access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often it is due to a connection drop while you were doing your transfer/request.

The server will reject you for about 10 minutes and then you can try again, but if you have a lot of connection drops, it will happen again.